# Syncfusion Server-Side event is not passing data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, syncfusion

I have a Asp.Net MVC project created from *Syncfusion ASP.New MVC (Essential JS 2)* VS template that is using Syncfusion's Data Grid. I can get the **CrudUpdate** event set in *CrudUrl* to fire at the server, however the *value* returned to **CrudUpdate** is empty. *action* parameter seems correctly set.

If I cast the value as Object, I get back a not-null, but VS cannot interrogate it. My guess is some weirdness in the way the value is cast or returned.

Has anyone got a complete working sample of the Syncfusion grid using the CrudUrl method with MVC (not asp). I am also guessing I may have some dependency issue.

**View**

```
@Html.EJS().Grid("CrudUrl").DataSource(dataManager => { dataManager.Url("/TestGrid2/UrlDatasource").CrudUrl("/TestGrid2/CrudUpdate").Adaptor("UrlAdaptor"); }).Columns(col =>
{

    col.Field("RowKey").IsPrimaryKey(true).Add();
    col.Field("PartitionKey").Add();
    col.Field("sourceResourceId").Add();
    col.Field("imagesLocation").Add();
    col.Field("imagesResourceGroup").Add();
    col.Field("imagePrefix").Add();
    col.Field("imageVersion").Add();

}).AllowPaging().Toolbar(new List<string>() { "Search", "Add", "Edit", "Delete", "Update", "Cancel" }).EditSettings(edit => { edit.AllowAdding(true).AllowEditing(true).AllowDeleting(true); }).Render()
```

**Controller**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services;
using DB;
//using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Syncfusion.EJ2.Base;

namespace VMSSManagmentConsole.Controllers
{
    public class TestGrid2Controller : Controller
    {
        private ModelContainer db = new ModelContainer();
        public ActionResult TestGrid2()
        {
            //var items = db.ManagementItems.ToList();
            //ViewBag.dataSource = items;
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult UrlDatasource([FromBody]DataManagerRequest dm)
        {
            IEnumerable DataSource = db.ManagementItems.ToList();
            DataOperations operation = new DataOperations();
            int count = DataSource.Cast<ManagementItem>().Count();
            if (dm.Skip != 0)
            {
                DataSource = operation.PerformSkip(DataSource, dm.Skip);   //Paging
            }
            if (dm.Take != 0)
            {
                DataSource = operation.PerformTake(DataSource, dm.Take);
            }
            var result = (ActionResult)(dm.RequiresCounts ? Json(new { result = DataSource, count = count }) : Json(DataSource));
            return result;
        }

        public ActionResult CrudUpdate([FromBody]ICRUDModel<ManagementItem> value, string action)
        {
            //if (value.action == "update")
            //{
            //    var ord = value.value;
            //    ManagementItem val = db.ManagementItems.Where(or => or.RowKey == ord.RowKey).FirstOrDefault();
            //    val.imagePrefix = ord.imagePrefix;
            //    val.imagesLocation = ord.imagesLocation;
            //    val.imagesResourceGroup = ord.imagesResourceGroup;
            //    val.imageVersion = ord.imageVersion;
            //    val.sourceResourceId = ord.sourceResourceId;
            //}
            //else if (value.action == "insert")
            //{
            //    db.ManagementItems.Add(value.value);
            //}
            //else if (value.action == "remove")
            //{
            //    db.ManagementItems.Remove(db.ManagementItems.Where(or => or.RowKey == value.key.ToString()).FirstOrDefault());
            //    return Json(value);
            //}
            //return Json(value.value);
            return null;
        }

        public class ICRUDModel<T> where T : class
        {
            public string action { get; set; }

            public string table { get; set; }

            public string keyColumn { get; set; }

            public object key { get; set; }

            public T value { get; set; }

            public List<T> added { get; set; }

            public List<T> changed { get; set; }

            public List<T> deleted { get; set; }

            public IDictionary<string, object> @params { get; set; }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the DataGrid scaffold wizard. On the third page select DataSourceType = "Remote Data". A page and controller will be created with the correct code.

Answer (score 0):

For your reference, we have created a sample and perform CRUD actions. Please refer the attached sample for more information.

Sample: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/GridEJ2Mvc-914352281

The reported problem occurred when model mismatched. For Example, when we specify the number column field(EmployeeID) in grid but while inserting you did not specify the value for that column then it shows value as null in CrudUpdate, for this scenario you need to specify the nullable value for that field in model class as follows.

```
public class OrdersDetails
{
       public OrdersDetails(int OrderID, string CustomerId, int EmployeeId, double Freight, bool Verified, DateTime OrderDate, string ShipCity, string ShipName, string ShipCountry, DateTime ShippedDate, string ShipAddress)
        {
            this.OrderID = OrderID;
            this.CustomerID = CustomerId;
            this.EmployeeID = EmployeeId;
            . . . . .
       }
    public static List<OrdersDetails> GetAllRecords()
    {
        if (order.Count() == 0)
        {
            int code = 10000;
            for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            {
                order.Add(new OrdersDetails(code + 1, "ALFKI", i + 0, 2.3 * i, false, new DateTime(1991, 05, 15), "Berlin", "Simons bistro", "Denmark", new DateTime(1996, 7, 16), "Kirchgasse 6"));
                . . . . .
           }
        }
        return order;
    }

        public int? OrderID { get; set; }
        public string CustomerID { get; set; }
        public int? EmployeeID { get; set; } // it accept null value
        . . . . .
    }
```

}

If you still face the problem then share more details or below information that will helpful for us to validate further and provide a better solution as soon as possible.

•   Did the problem occurred for both update and insert?

•   Share package version details.

Regards,

Thavasianand S.